# For $\Omega$ an algebraic closure of $k$, why is $k[x]/(f)\otimes_k\Omega \cong \Omega^m$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, tensor-products

Let's fix a field $k$ and an algebraic closure $\Omega$ of $k$. For a monic, irreducible, separable polynomial $f\in k[x]$, let $f$ split over $\Omega$ as

$$f(x) = \prod_{i=1}^m (x - a_i).$$

I have been told that the following holds:

> $$\frac{k[x]}{(f)}\otimes_k\Omega\cong \prod_{i=1}^m \frac{\Omega[x]}{(x-a_i)} \cong \Omega^m.$$

I can see the Chinese Remainder Theorem in here, but the piece that is unclear to me is resolving the tensor as I'm not quite comfortable working with them yet. Why is the first isomorphism true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tensor with $\Omega$ above $k$ and write the *Chinese remainder theorem*:
$$k[x]/(f)\otimes_k\Omega\simeq \Omega[x]/(f)=\Omega[x]\Big/\Bigl( \textstyle\prod_{i=1}^m (x - a_i)\Bigr)\simeq  \prod_{i=1}^m \Omega[x]\big/(x - a_i)\simeq\Omega^m  $$
(we call apply it because $f$ is separable, so all its roots in $\Omega$ are distinct, hence the linear factors are pairwise coprime.)
'

Comment: Ah, I see my sticking point. Why is it true that $k[x]/(f)\otimes_k \Omega \cong\Omega[x]/(f)$?

Comment: This is independent from having a field and an algebraic closure: it's a general fact that, for any $R$-algebra $A$, $R[X]\otimes_RA\simeq A[X]$. As to the ideal, generators obviously map to generators. Is that clear?

Comment: It isn't immediately clear, but it's enough for me to make it clear for myself later. Thanks!

Comment: Don't forget that $R[X]$, as an $R$-module, is just the direct sum $R^{(\mathbf N)}$, so tensoring with $A$, you obtain  $A^{(\mathbf N)}$ by distributivity of the tensor product w.r.t. direct sums.